# show modal Bootstrap on catch exception

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, try-catch

I want to show a Bootstrap show modal in the catch exception

Bankend language: C#
Bootstrap v3.3.7

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try 
  {
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    {

    }
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    label.Tex = ex.toString()<
    //show modal here
  }
}
```

thank you for you time and help.

Comment: look here for WebForms and bootstrap modal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172311/display-bootstrap-modal-from-asp-net-webforms

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ScriptManager`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
             "SuccessfullSave",
             @"$('#SuccessfullSave').modal('show'); 
               $('.modal-backdrop').appendTo('#aspnetForm');",
             true);
```

Let me explain this code:

The `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` is a method that allows you to inject into your web page javascript

The parameters you pass are:

1. the page (`this`)
2. the type [use `GetType()`]
3. the "name" or key of the script
4. the actual JavaScript itself (which in this case is the JQuery code
   to show a modal `$('#SuccessfullSave').modal('show');` where #successfullSave is the id of the modal and `$('.modal-backdrop').appendTo('#aspnetForm');` is code to correct
   styles so the modal is up in front and not weirdly placed behind a
   gray see through background)
5. and the last parameter is a `bool` value saying insert this code
   inside of script tags

This completed code would look something like below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try 
   {
      if (!IsPostBack) 
      {

      }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        label.Text = ex.toString();
        //HERE IS WHERE YOU PUT THIS
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
             "ErrorMessage",
             @"$('#NameOfModal').modal('show'); 
               $('.modal-backdrop').appendTo('#aspnetForm');",
             true);
    }
}
```

To close the modal: 
Instead of using the traditional modal dismiss that comes with bootstrap you need to call the opposite of `$('#NameOfModal').modal('show');` That is `$('#NameOfModal').modal('hide');` or you can just click outside the modal

Comment: it works!! but I can not close it, when a press Close or "x" button in the show modal, how can I close it?